# Django: Built in way to generate HTML sitemaps (not XML)

Tags: django, sitemap

We're using the [django sitemap framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/) to generate a search engine friendly xml sitemap. It works fine. It's nice to use and customize to your own needs.

I know I could rewrite the template used for the xml sitemap or generate a list of all pages in our system with normal db queries and alike, but it's hard to believe that there is not a preconfigured solution for such a common problem.

I just want the same list as used in our xml sitemap in a normal (html) frontend view.

**TL;DR:**

What's the best/default way to build a html sitemap intended to help people finding stuff on our site (instead of bots)?

Answer (score 6):

you can embed the xml generated from the sitemap processor in a standard html

```
    url(r'^sitemap/','django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', \
                      {'sitemaps'      : sitemaps,
                       'template_name' : '<yoursite>/usr_sitemap.html',
                       'mimetype'      : 'None'}),
```

setting the 'mimetype' to none will allow you to include html code in the template used for the generation. This produces html containing the sitemap xml code. You then need to style it using css. A sample template(usr_sitemap.html) would be:

---

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}  << the content section of the base.html 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" type='text/css' href='{% static '<yoursite>/your_css.css' %}'?>
<urlset
  xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
{% spaceless %}
{% for url in urlset %}
  <url>
    <loc>{{ url.location }}</loc>
    {% if url.lastmod %}<lastmod>{{ url.lastmod|date:"Y-m-d" }}</lastmod>{% endif %}
    {% if url.changefreq %}<changefreq>{{ url.changefreq }}</changefreq>{% endif %}
    {% if url.priority %}<priority>{{ url.priority }}</priority>{% endif %}
    <news:news>
      <news:tag1> blabla  </news:tag1>
      <news:tag2> blabla </news:tag2>
    </news:news>
   </url>
{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
</urlset>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It's not mimetype, but `'content_type': None`